# what is the best method to check if statement being false or undefined

Tags: javascript

what is the best method to check if statement being false or undefined but sometimes may not be true boolean

I am trying make this cleaner

```
var result = 'some time result is undefined'

if (result === false || 'undefined' && instantMessage === false || 'undefined'){
// do something
}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's not very clear right now.

Comment: `if (!result)`? It's unclear what specific problem you're having.

Comment: You can compare the value of `result` against `undefined`, `true` or `false`, depending on your needs, using the [strict equality operator (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

Comment: every method is best here we are not looping just comparing for truthy and falsy or undefined

Comment: The updated code won't work at all like you think it will. Now it's even less clear; do you mean `undefined` or do you mean the string `"undefined"`?

Comment: I need to do something if my result is false or undefined or null. My result sometimes my be a value or array

Comment: `if (!result)`? It's unclear what specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (result !== undefined && result) {
 //do something
}
```

I agree with above that question is not very clear.
My snippet would work if you want something to be done only when it is 'true' boolean value

Comment: `result` checks for truthiness, not boolean true.

Comment: I am looking for solution that will check if result is false or undefined or null. When result is true will will not be a boolean it may be an array of values

Comment: @JerrySeigle And what specifically is wrong with `if (!result)`???

Comment: does (!result) mean false boolan or does it mean that result has some type of value

Comment: @JerrySeigle https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: !result worked. haha. I have been up working over 14 hours. I guest I am starting to over think now